# Check if element exists in view in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to click on an element before which i need to check if an element exists and then click on the element.
The challenge here is that the element is located at the end of the page and the below code fails to find the element. While i scroll to the end of the page and run the below code, the element exists and it clicks on the element. How can i check if the element exists in the entire page rather than scrolling down the page to the element in view?

```
public static boolean CheckIfElementExists(By by)
    {
        if(driver().findElements(by).size() > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If element is dynamic one, it will not be loaded until its within [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). How you checked in DOM if element is present without scroll? Looks like it may be the scenario.